# Angular add class from component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this code which allow me to scroll in specific DIV, what I try to do is to add temporary class into that div when it's scrolled and remove the class let say after one second.

```
scrollTo (id) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      var titleELe = document.getElementById(id); // my destination div on scroll
      this.scrollMeElement.scrollToPoint(0, titleELe.offsetTop, 1000); // add class to it for 1 second
    }, 100);
};
```

**How to do that?**

## Update

I have made this changes:

`component`

```
scrolledItem: boolean = false; // added

constructor(...){...}

scrollTo (id) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      var titleELe = document.getElementById(id);
      this.scrolledItem = true; // added
      this.scrollMeElement.scrollToPoint(0, titleELe.offsetTop, 1000);
    }, 100);
    this.scrolledItem = false; // added
};
```

Then in my `html` I've add `[class.active] = "scrolledItem"` like

```
<div id="{{message.id}}" [class.active] = "scrolledItem" class="receiver"></div>
```

This does add class to my div but there is 2 issues:

1. It add class to all rows not only destination div.
2. It doesn't remove `active` class from my div.

**screenshot**

[image: one]

**Any idea?**

Comment: What about titleEle.classList.add('test-class') ?

Comment: @HungCung updated my question

Comment: @HungCung your code also works (better than my update part) but still won't be removed

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/chimung-angular-8-gc8kxz this is my demo that i make for you to scroll + active an element. I will explain later in fully answer but need take a lunch now. Check it

Comment: My answer is posted https://stackoverflow.com/a/62422520/3905676

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
// Div to scroll
<div class="component-placehoder" #componentPlacehoder></div>

// create view child
 @ViewChild('componentPlacehoder', { static: true })
    componentPlacehoder: ElementRef;

// scroll to div  
this.componentPlacehoder.nativeElement.scrollIntoView(true, { block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth' });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should use template variable `item` to pass into function scroll.

```
<div class="message" *ngFor="let message of listMessage" (click)="scroll(item)" #item>
  <span>Message {{ message }}</span>
</div>
```

So in your function you can access `offsetTop`, `classList` of `HTMLElement` in order to scroll and manipulate class.

```
scroll(item: HTMLElement) {
    window.scrollTo(0, item.offsetTop)
    if (this.oldElemt) {
      this.oldElemt.classList.remove('active')
    }
    item.classList.add('active')
    this.oldElemt = item
  }
```

Using a variable to save old element like `oldElemt`.

This is link [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/chimung-angular-8-gc8kxz)

Comment: sorry but no this wasn't what i'm looking for. What I'm trying to do is to give temporary background to origin message (here is sample image for you https://ibb.co/rM844zq )